# Can't catch problem with java debugger jdb

Tags: java, ubuntu, debugging, jdb

I have the application which crashes without any message. I try to debug it with jdb. I run jdb with command:

```
/opt/app# jdb -classpath /opt/app/app.jar:app.Main
Initializing jdb ...
> catch throw
Deferring all throw.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
> run app.Main
run  app.Main
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
>
VM Started: DEBUG [COMMON] Init logger files: dir = "/opt/app/log" stdout = "null" stderr = "app.err.log" common = "app.all.log"
```

But no throws actually are caught, instead of it only one word appears when app crashes: "Killed". And nothing more.

Also, when i kill app with "kill -9", the message says "App has been disconnected from debugger".

So what should I set up in jdb to obtain more information about a crash?

Comment: Whats the app doing?

Comment: Make sure your application contains no **Ignored Exceptions** (catch blocks that contain nothing).

Comment: App makes recording (using ffmpeg) and saves records on ftp.

It doesn't have ignored exceptions for sure. Also we have this app on multiple machines, but the problem occurs only with this machine. Java version is the same (1.8).